# open docx from c# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and save changes after closeing msword

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx, savechanges

im using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to open my docx using this code:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(); Document document = ap.Documents.Open(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\MSWordFile.docx");
```

but i want when user save and close opened msword, my app can detect it by some event and do something like getchanges and save it to server.

any ideas?

Comment: You will need to monitor the file for changes on filesystem level.

Comment: You can monitor the Document.Close event from your code, by adding an event handler to the `ap` object for the `DocumentBeforeClose` event. Note that it's not certain that the user will actually allow the document to close when the event fires, so the event should check whether the Document is still in the `ap.Documents` collection. It's also not certain whether the file lock will be released immediately...